# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_MaterialIcons.default.propTypes.style')

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import {Modal, Image, ScrollView, StatusBar, View,  FlatList , Animated, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import { AntDesign, MaterialIcons, Ionicons, Entypo, FontAwesome} from '@expo/vector-icons'
import CutString from '../methods/CutString'
//import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'
import { ResizeMode } from 'expo-av'
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player'
//import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const FormationBox = (props)=>{
const data = props.data
return(



{data.title}
{data.desc}


)
}

export default FormationBox

======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================bugs:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_MaterialIcons.default.propTypes.style')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.10.199:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:175221:3 in global code

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
  at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
  at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

Comment: Havent really got a clue about react so Im not giving an answer but should there not be a semi-colon between the assertion of const data and the return statement. I have a rough idea react should be javascript-like and if an error happens in the promise, the value of FormationBox is undefined, which the exception handler doesnt truly handle but just reports. No clue about react but is it a semi-colon error?

Comment: Do you know what you npm installed before this? I'm having an identical issue, something must be deprecated somewhere